# Drupal 7 Multiple alias for nodes

Tags: drupal-7, alias, drupal-views

I need my nodes to have multiple aliases for example www.example.com/1/title-of-node.  should be opened by www.example.com/2/title-of-node or www.example.com/3/title-of-node. Does there exist any functionality for this in drupal ? Pathauto doesn't provide this.

Answer (score 2):

for this you have to create a custom module i am writting pesudo code bellow

```
 step1 : create a custom trigger in module
 step2 : write db_insert query in a function which will be call just after a node is saved in trigger
```

db_insert code is given is below

```
 $nid = db_insert('url_alias') 
        ->fields(array(
          'alias' => 'another alise',
          'source' => 'node/'.$node->id,
        ))
        ->execute();
```

in drupal **url_alise** table is reposible to keep alise with respect to node.